# Drone.io Failure to get build config 404 Not found []

Tags: drone.io

I am having trouble with my webhook. When pushing to master I get:

> failure to get build config for MyOrganization/Repo. GET https://api.github.com/repos/MyOrganization/Repo/contents/.drone.yml?ref=ec9ec47df4757cdfef97dfb445b1896d929687c6: 404 Not Found []

My drone.yml looks like this

```
---
pipeline:
  build:
    image: node:6
    commands:
      - npm install
      - npm test
```

I have registered my user who is and Admin for the Organisation. Perhaps the cloning is failing? Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not a cloning issue because Drone uses the GitHub API to fetch your yaml file prior to cloning. This error would indicate that either a) the .drone.yml does not exist for that ref so github returns a 404 or b) the GitHub account used to activate the repository had its oauth credentials revoked. This means the oauth token stored in Drone is no longer valid and then GitHub returns a 404

Comment: Ok thanks for the quick reply, I repaired the webhooks and double checked the file name and contents. All is correct now, I had left the first . off the filename having only drone.yml. However now pushing to remote has no effect to the server logs and running drone build start org/repo returns `strconv.Atoi: parsing "": invalid syntax`

Comment: Ok I am making some progress, there were quite a few versions of the docs online and some didn't use the key `pipeline` and I had removed it trying to fix my issue. But it appears to be working now. Thanks! For anyone having similar problems check the name `.drone.yml` and keep the `pipeline` object

Comment: docs.drone.io is new home for the latest docs, fyi

Comment: Oh very good, I was using readme.drone.io I think.

Comment: @Brenwell How do you fix the issue `strconv.Atoi: parsing "": invalid syntax`. I hit the same today. ymlint the `.drone.yml`, it is valid, and my pipeline runs well in drone UI. But can't start by `drone build start name/reop`

Comment: fixed by http://discourse.drone.io/t/solved-drone-cli-build-start/248